# Parity checker in verilog only calculates a result once

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm trying to write a code to check for even/odd parity in Verilog.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module ParityChecker(
input [7:0] bitt,
output reg ans
);

integer count = 0;
integer i = 0;

initial
begin
    count = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=7; i=i+1)
    begin
        if(bitt[i]==1)
        count = count + 1;
    end
    if(count%2==0)  //even parity
    ans = 1;
    else
    ans = 0;
    
end

endmodule
```

Here's the testbench code:

```
module ParityChecker_tb;

reg [7:0] bitToSend;
wire answer;

ParityChecker mygate(.bitt(bitToSend), .ans(answer));

initial
begin
$monitor(bitToSend, answer);

bitToSend = 8'b11111101;
#10
bitToSend = 8'b11111100;
#10
bitToSend = 8'b1111111;

end
endmodule
```

However, I'm only getting one as output for the variable answer, no matter what. There seems to be some problem in the logical part. What could be it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in `module ParityChecker` you used `initial` to implement your logic, which is only executed once.

You can implement it as `always@` block, like

```
always@(bitt)
begin
    // All your logic...
    // Or even simpler,
    ans = ~^bitt;
end
```

The simplest way would be:

```
module ParityChecker(
input [7:0] bitt,
output ans
);
    assign ans = ~^bitt;
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out...What does assign ans = ~^bitt; do by the way? What would be the first operand of this XOR gate?

Comment: @archity It's a reduction XNOR gate which XNOR all bits of the operand together.

Comment: Basically it converts a vector to scaler. Input can be of multiple bits but output consists only one bit.